# Mercurial plugin for visual studio code

Tags: version-control, mercurial, visual-studio-code

I'm developping a project with React.
The IDE I use for React (ES6) is Visual Code and the version control is Mercurial Hg.

(I'm in Windows and I get issue with Atom, that's why I use Visual Code).

My problem is I cannot find a plugin for Visual Code to manage the source control with Hg.

Is anyone know a plugin and can help me ?

Comment: This is now implemented according to this [comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/205#issuecomment-288525081) on github.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @mrcrowl mentionned in his comment, this is the plugin I was loking for

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrcrowl.hg

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio Code was designed to be directly integrated with Git, so currently there aren't any resources for Visual Studio Code that add Mercurial integration, however, many people have already [expressed their interest in the idea](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7752945-support-for-mercurial) on Visual Studio Code's UserVoice.

If you really want to, you could always create a simple plugin for Visual Studio Code that adds a couple commands to the editor, which could then be used to help you control the Mercurial CLI.

Comment: The UserVoice forum for VS Code has been deprecated. See the [Add VCS Mercurial Support](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/205) feature request in GitHub instead.

Comment: Now available as an extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrcrowl.hg